# SQL Query returns multiple rows of the same record when View includes one-to-many table

Tags: sql-server, llblgenpro

In MS-SQL, I have a View 'ListingResult' which contains rows from tables 'ListingCategoryXref' and 'Listing'. This is the View statement:

```
SELECT        
    dbo.Listing.ListingName,  
    dbo.Listing.ListingId,  
    dbo.ListingCategoryXref.CategoryId
FROM    dbo.Listing INNER JOIN
        dbo.ListingCategoryXref ON dbo.Listing.ListingId = dbo.ListingCategoryXref.ListingId

GROUP BY 
    dbo.Listing.ListingName, 
    dbo.Listing.ListingId, 
        dbo.ListingCategoryXref.CategoryId
```

Listings can have many rows in ListingCategoryXref, thus.

```
ListingResult (View)
Listing (table)
ListingId   ListingName     StateId
1           Toms bar        3
2           French place    5

ListingCategoryXref (table)
ListingId   CategoryId
1           10
1           15
```

The query below returns a row per Listing per ListingCategoryXref.

```
SELECT TOP(26) 
        [ListingResult].[ListingId],
        [ListingResult].[ListingName]
FROM    [ListingResult]     
WHERE   [ListingResult].[StateId] = 3
```

So 'Tom's Bar' is returned twice as it has two categories. I figure I can either change the query above, or change the ListingResult View in SQL. I still need to return 26 results which I can't dictate if I use a wrapped select statement with `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ListingId`. (Is that true?) I'm using LLBLGen to access the DB so I'd prefer to change the view, if that is possible? Apologies for my newness to SQL being that obvious.

Comment: Hey @Rufyan, I'm not quite sure what you're asking - please could you clarify?

Comment: What's the purpose of the GROUP BY in your view? It exactly matches the SELECT and doesn't seem like it would do anything.

Comment: @JohnLBevan my question is how do I return just one instance of each record in the listing table.

Comment: Say ListingId 1 has Category Ids 10 and 15, which of these would you like to select?

Comment: @RobP I left the group by in as the example I used was an edited version from Design in SSMS. Does that confuse the issue?

Comment: @wewesthemenace any instances - I'm not actually returning any ListingCategory data with this particular query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the query above, the following result will be returned...

**ListingName** | **ListingId** | **CategoryId**
Toms bar | 1 | 10
Toms bar |1 | 15

If you only want Toms bar to be returned once, you'll need to remove the CategoryId column from the result set, and the group by clause, or add CategoryId to an agrgate function, and remove it from the group by clause i.e.

```
SELECT
    dbo.Listing.ListingName,
    dbo.Listing.ListingId,
    COUNT(dbo.ListingCategoryXref.CategoryId) as Categories
FROM dbo.Listing 
    INNER JOIN dbo.ListingCategoryXref ON dbo.Listing.ListingId = dbo.ListingCategoryXref.ListingId
GROUP BY dbo.Listing.ListingName, dbo.Listing.ListingId
```

Which will return...

**ListingName** | **ListingId** | **Categories**
Toms bar | 1 | 2

Can you give an example of what you would like to see?

Comment: That works perfectly. Thanks @Spock. It was quite simple in the end.